# Change color of a type of text like header/footer

Tags: header-footer, color, fancyhdr

Can we change the color of a logical type of text, say every header or every footer, by a single command? Header and footer is using `fancyhdr`.

I believe it should be a `\renewcommand` but won't it affect dependent packages like `fancyhdr`? I could define newer macros from the one which fancyhdr uses like `\rfoot` or `\cfoot`, to say `\rfootcolored` or `\cfootcolored`. But then I have to redesign the entire header/footer from scratch...which I don't want to do..

A MWE..

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-6]

\section{lipsumsection}
\lipsum[7-10]

\chapter{Lipsum2}
\lipsum[2-7]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: But how to do it will depend on which part you want to modify.

Comment: @VineetMenon: You should also include information on how you generate your headers and footers, by posting a minimal example. Otherwise someone might try to answer explaining how to do it with `fancyhdr`, and then you might answer "Actually, I'm using `memoir`, and this approach isn't working". You should always try to make questions as concrete and detailed as possible.

Comment: Probably an `ifelse` statement would be the simplest way here.

Comment: i have put `fancyhdr` as the tag..I thought it was sufficient...

Comment: @VineetMenon: I think it would really help if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the internal `fancyhdr` macros `\f@nch@head` and `\f@nch@foot` (and in case you want colored rules, also `\headrule` and `\footrule`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\f@nch@head}{\rlap}{\color{red}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{red}\hrule}{}{}
\patchcmd{\f@nch@foot}{\rlap}{\color{green}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{green}\hrule}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-6]

\section{lipsumsection}
\lipsum[7-10]

\chapter{Lipsum2}
\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The relevant internal macros in the `fancyhdr` package have since changed from `\@fancyhead` and `\@fancyfoot` to `\f@nch@head` and `\f@nch@foot`, respectively.